# unblock email address outlook

Tags: java, outlook, exchange-server

I was sending email from my Java EE application. For testing I sent too many emails to my office email address. Now the server has blocked the email address and no body is receiving that domain. How can I unblock the email address. Should I contact IT to unblock the domain from the exchange server or I can do it from my end.
(There is no problem with the application as I have tested with yahoo, gmail, live, etc).
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a programming-related question. It's either about outlook server administration (then it belongs to serverfault.com) or about how to use Microsoft Outlook (superuser.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont be possible to unblock your `email address` **programmatically**. You need to contact **Admin** ( who monitors server).

And next time, make sure you are not spamming any email server (as it goes with all other email clients )

Answer (score 0):

Contact your IT Department and then use an external email for testing